# How to find a file name in mysql Like %_1.jpg% without finding _11.jpg

Tags: mysql

My script is simple.

```
SELECT file_name FROM images WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `file_name` LIKE '%_1.jpg'
```

When I run this in mysql it returns (id)_1.jpg and (id)_11.jpg
How can I make it only find (id)_1.jpg?

Answer (score 8):

You have to escape the underscore:

```
SELECT file_name FROM images WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `file_name` LIKE '%\_1.jpg'
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 1):

It's because `_` matches *any single character,* rather than the literal underscore.

You can escape the underscore `\_` but I would give serious thought to using `regexp` rather than `like` since it's far more expressive and flexible.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html for details (on both the use of `_` in `like`, and the power of `regexp`).